# how do i make a automatic python file importer (in python)?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am asking like a extensions, like there are like 3 files of python and you want to import it in, but you don't know their names, maybe its a self-made one or imported. What I want its like :

```
for i(python file) in file(location of folder that holds these python files):
    # i dont know how to import that file using import, so help me with that too
    import file(that file)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `glob`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Read [the official python packaging documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/) for all the gory details.

The most basic way is to iterate over `pkgutil.iter_modules()` to find the modules, then use `importlib.import_module(name)` to load them.